# New altcoin. Cpuminer gives me "booo"

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development, genesis-block

I made a new altcoin based on "INSaNe" https://github.com/CryptoCoderz/INSN

I changed genesis hashes using this code:

```
    if (true  && (genesis.GetHash() != hashGenesisBlock)) {
                     //This will figure out a valid hash and Nonce if you're
                    // creating a different genesis block:
                        uint256 hashTarget = CBigNum().SetCompact(genesis.nBits).getuint256();
                        while (genesis.GetHash() > hashTarget)
                           {
                               ++genesis.nNonce;
                               if (genesis.nNonce == 0)
                               {
                                   printf("NONCE WRAPPED, incrementing time");
                                   ++genesis.nTime;
                               }
                           }
                    }
            printf("block.GetHash() == %s\n0x", genesis.GetHash().ToString().c_str());
            printf("block.hashMerkleRoot == %s\n", genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str());
            printf("block.nTime = %u \n", genesis.nTime);
            printf("block.nNonce = %u \n", genesis.nNonce);
```

So i started coin with two clients on localhost and tried to mine it with cpuminer-multi by tpruvot https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi, but miner always gives me booo, please help me...

My OS: Kubuntu 16.04

There is no setgenerate or generate function in this cryptocurrency

```
00:15:45 setgenerate
00:15:45 Method not found (code -32601)
00:16:03 generate
00:16:03 Method not found (code -32601)
```

Cpuminer output:

```
Current block is 1
[2017-07-19 00:16:32] Switching to getwork, gbt version 7
[2017-07-19 00:16:36] CPU #2: 26.28 kH/s
[2017-07-19 00:16:38] accepted: 0/1 (diff 0.000), 26.28 kH/s booooo
```

Here is difficulty for mainnet:

```
bnProofOfWorkLimit = CBigNum(~uint256(0) >> 18);
```

Here is block time:

```
static const int64_t BLOCK_SPACING = 5 * 60;
/** Block spacing minimum */
static const int64_t BLOCK_SPACING_MIN = 3.5 * 60;
/** Block spacing maximum */
static const int64_t BLOCK_SPACING_MAX = 7.5 * 60;
```

Here is block version:

```
static const int CURRENT_VERSION=1;
```

Comment: Can you show how you us how/where you changed the time in the code.

Comment: How did you actually solve this problem?
Could you please share it? Many thanks,
BRs,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

fixed! The main trouble is time. I set my time in genesis hash +3hrs, i changed my pc time +3hrs and voila! Mining works!